# referring to a style property using a variable

Tags: javascript, css

In the project I am working on, I have to access the style property of an element using a variable. 
   For example: Normally, to change the background color of an element we write:

```
var element = document.getElementById("element");
element.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
```

But, If I declare a variable holding "backgroundColor" and then I want to change the property of background color by referring to the value in this this variable, then how could it be done. 
    I tried these:

```
var property = "backgroundColor";
eval(element.style.property = "blue");
```

But it didn't work. I am not sure of any other way I can accomplish this. If there is any solution for this, then please answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `[]` notation, eg

```
element.style[property] = 'blue';
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties

Comment: hi.. thanks... What if it is not a style attribute and a normal html attribute like innerhtml. can I access like this, element.[property] = "something"

Comment: @SameekshaKumari attributes are not properties but yes, `innerHTML` is a property so you could have `element['innerHTML'] = 'something'`. The string `'innerHTML'` could be stored in another variable, eg `var p = 'innerHTML'; element[p] = 'value'`

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like :

```
var property = "backgroundColor" ;

element.style[property] = "blue" ;
```

This will let you access the `background` attribute

Answer (score 2):

This is because its firing sweet error,

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string
```

`document.getElementById("element").style` -->  `Style Object [object CSSStyleDeclaration]`

and `backgroundImage` is a property  of `style Object`.

To access property of style object you can use `[]`

```
var property = "backgroundColor";
element.style[property] = 'blue'; // will set property of element.
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way to get var not only with style object, but also with it's value?
Similar like the code below. I know this code doesn't work, i wrote it only for better explanation what i am asking.

```
var property = "backgroundColor = "blue" ";
element.style[property];
```

Comment: can you please ask your question in the comments or create new question ?